# Why does Entity Framework try to build an already existing database?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, migration, ssms

In both my Services and WebSite `Web.config` file, I have the following connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyDBConnect" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=MyDB;User Id=tester;Password=abc123*123;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I manually ran my database build script and have confirmed in the SSMS UI: (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB (SQL Server 13.0.40001 - 8Protons) > Databases > MyDB

While running the project and going to the login screen, an exception is thrown at:

```
var entity = GetAll().Include(p => p.Role).FirstOrDefault(p => p.Email == userName && p.Password == encryptedPassword && p.IsActive);
```

with the following message

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'MyDB'.

Why is the solution trying to CREATE a table when it already exists? So I went to the table is SSMS and elevated this user's permissions to create a table. The error that now gets thrown is:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: There is already an object named 'MyTable' in the
>   database.

For context, this is after I've cloned someone's EF solution, built it, and am attempting to sign in to a log-in page that the solution is running. So this is a fresh solution on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Review the constructor for your database context. For example,

```
public MyDBContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
    : base(nameOrConnectionString)
{
    this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    this.Database.CommandTimeout = 60;

    IDatabaseInitializerCreator creator = new DatabaseInitializerCreator();
    Database.SetInitializer(creator.Create());
}
```

The last two lines will make sure the database and its tables are created, if not already existing and matching exactly what exists.